# why local timeZone String is getting appended in the UTC date?

Tags: java

I want to get a Date Object in UTC Time Zone so i am converting it first to a String which is returing me correct UTC Date String but when i am again parsing it to Date object then Local Time Zone String(ie. IST) is getting appended in that  Date instead of UTC.

```
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String estTime = timeFormat.format(date);
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(estTime);
```

Comment: You want to get current time in UTC?

Comment: yes ,but in form of Date Object only..

Answer (score 2):

A `Date` doesn't have a timezone, it represents a moment in time. It holds the time in milliseconds.

You can't have a `Date` with a format, it doesn't work that way. If you need to show the `Date` in a GUI, console or anywhere else, that's when you use a `SimpleDateFormat` like you did to change it to a `String` in the format you want.

Comment: The Database will use its own format to hold the `Date`, it doesn't need a timezone either. Unless your field in the databse for the `Date` is a `String` (or equivalent to it), you don't need to do anything to the date. Use a `PreparedStatement` and pass the `Date` to it directly.

Comment: in that case,the time stored will be server specific??? i need to store time(As per UTC timezone only)..??

Comment: No. It won't be. The database will also just hold the representation of the instant in time but it will handle by itself how it will store that information, which might be different then how Java does it.